# Update cell location in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I wanted to get the cell from one sheet based on cell value in other sheet
eg.

2 sheets : x,y

I want cell value from sheet "y" and its cell is "A" and column value of "A" depend on sheet x and cell B1

```
  eg. y!A(x!$B1+1)
```

However,y!A gets evaluated first and I get error.

Can anyone suggest solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This formula should do it:

```
=INDIRECT("y!r1c"&x!B1, FALSE)
```

This assumes x!B1 holds the column as a number

Comment: I don't want to use xl built in formulas.

Comment: @Dave: I guess your formula should be `=INDIRECT("y!r"&(x!B1+1)&"c1", FALSE)`

Comment: Is this functionality can be achieved only using simple formula not using XL built in formula lie INDIRECT

Comment: @mat_vee - not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by simple formula versus built in formula? You tagged your question as Excel formula, do you want something else?

Comment: simple formula =<cell location> excel formula = INDIRECT/VLOOKUP <cell_location>

Comment: @Dave: Since you ignored my comment. I was forced to post a separate answer :)

Comment: @Dave: Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

> y!A(x!$B1+1)

You can use INDIRECT like Dave mentioned

```
y is the Sheet
A is the column
(x!$B1+1) is the row
```

However since you want to pickup the row part and not the column part, Dave's formula needs to be written as

`=INDIRECT("y!r"&(x!B1+1)&"c1", FALSE)`

Alternatively you can use `OFFSET`

`=OFFSET(y!A1,x!B1,0)`

No need to Add `+1` Offset will take care of that.